# Specify type maps in Dapper.Net

Tags: oracle, dapper

Is there a way in Dapper.Net to plug-in code for mapping between types? I'm using Dapper.Net with oracle and Dapper.Net will not cast my int16 (that's how my boolean is represented in oracle) to a bool. I looked at the code and I think Dapper.Net is expecting the types returned from the DataReader to match up with with the types on the object. I guess I could update the code to do what I want but then I'd have to maintain it from version to version.

Comment: The type map in the static constructor of SqlMapper can be updated without much work. I guess its the most pragmatic way to do it.

Comment: This seems to only relate to mapping parameters when executing queries not actually mapping the data returned from  the reader to properties on an object. I was looking for a way to tell Dapper how to convert the type of value coming from the reader to the associate property type.

Comment: Hm, I'd have to check that. You could also map your int16 to another property, say "fakeBool" (with a corresponding type) and do the casting in your "real" property accessor.

Answer (score -2):

One option is to cast within the query, something like:

```
declare @val as int;
set @val = 1;
select CAST(@val as bit);
```

Note: The above code is for SQL Server, but you should get the idea...

Comment: thanks, I considered that but then casting becomes something I always have to remember to do rather than a solution that I can implement and forget. I decided to go with Petapoco instead which uses the same IL magic for speed but provides plugin points where I can set conventions for type conversions

Comment: Oracle does not have a `bit` data type, so this is not a valid answer.

Comment: In the current version of Dapper an Oracle number value of 1 and 0 will be mapped to a CLR Boolean value of true and false respectively.

Comment: Downvoted because the question has nothing to do with SQL Server.